# No resource identifier found for attribute 'Layout_below' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I'm very very new to this- just done the start of beginners android development- so i'm sorry for this stupid question :(

I have tried to run my app to my phone and got the following errors:

```
C:\Users\melod\AndroidStudioProjects\CardForMelody\app\src\main\re\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(36) No resource identifier found for attribute 'Layout_below' in package 'android'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\melod\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Can anyone help? My code looks like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.cardformelody.MainActivity">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/rosetrim"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Melody"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    android:fontFamily="Thin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:text="Melody..." />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/thebest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:layout_below="@id/Melody"
    android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
    android:text="You're the best"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lovemelody"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:Layout_below="id@/thebest"
    android:text="LOVE MELODY" />
```

Comment: Looks like you've got couple of typos: `android:Layout_below="id@/thebest"` should really be `android:layout_below="@+id/thebest"` - with lowercase `l` in `layout_below` and `@+id` instead of `id@`

Answer (score 1):

In your Last TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lovemelody"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:Layout_below="id@/thebest"
    android:text="LOVE MELODY" />
```

Change this line

```
 android:Layout_below="id@/thebest"
```

to this

```
 android:layout_below="id@/thebest"
```

you are write `Layout_below` but it's `layout_below` so change it.